# New to bind_param, what's wrong with this code?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
        // Insert the new user into the database
        // This WORKS, and was copied from an example
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: MEMBER. Please contact the developer.');
            }
            $insert_stmt->close();



            // If user inserted, add place with user as owner
            // This DOESN'T work, and was added by me
            //$ownerid = $mysqli->lastInsertId();
            $placename = $_POST['placename'];
            $placename = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $placename);
            $location = $_POST['autocomplete'];
            $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $location);
            if ($place_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO places (member_owner, location, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
                $place_stmt->bind_param('iss', 1, $location, $placename);
                if (! $place_stmt->execute()) {
                    header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: PLACE. Please contact the developer.');
                }
            }
            $place_stmt->close();
        }

        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
```

I can confirm that the 2 variables `$location` and `$placename` are successfully retrieved. The result I get from running this code is that the `members` table is successfully updated, but the `places` table is not and the script dumps me into a blank HTML.

Comment: FYI you have a subtle bug. Both header calls will be called (error.php redirect and register_success.php redirect) since you aren't exiting/dying after the error redirect

Comment: Also, a blank HTML page typically indicates a fatal PHP error, please check your logs

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also `if(!$place_stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` - You should also add `exit;` after each header.

Comment: I'd use an `else { header('Location: ./register_success.php'); exit; }` on both `if` conditions and remove `header('Location: ./register_success.php');` from where you have it now. Also check your column types.

Comment: You shouldnt be using `mysqli_real_escape_string` if you are going to bind the params...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that `bind_param` doesn't like to accept hard-coded values. I was trying to "test" my code by inserting a value of 1 into a column before I messed around with trying to get the last inserted ID. The error reporting suggested by Fred really helped (as did other suggestions, as you can see I've implemented).

The altered code:

```
    // Insert the new user into the database 
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ./error.php?err=Registration failure: MEMBER. Please contact the developer.');
            exit;
        }
        $insert_stmt->close();

        // If user inserted, add place with user as owner
        $ownerid = $mysqli->insert_id;
        if ($place_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO places (member_owner, location, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
            $place_stmt->bind_param('iss', $ownerid, $location, $placename);
            if (! $place_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ./error.php?err=Registration failure: PLACE. Please contact the developer.');
                exit;
            }
        }
        $place_stmt->close();
        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
    }
```

Thanks for all the help!